# Coproducts of join-semilattices

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, lattice-orders

I am trying to describe what is the coproduct of two objects in the category of join-semilattices (with a top element). Does anyone have an idea or a reference to read ?

Comment: Do morphisms in the category preserve the top element?

Comment: Also: Presumably a join-semilattice is required to have a bottom element (the empty join), and morphisms preseve the bottom element, right?

Comment: Yes I suppose that morphisms preserves the top element. For the bottom element, I do not think so. If the semilattice is infinite, it can live without a bottom element. Am I right ?

Comment: Well, it's a matter of convention. For me, a join semilattice always has a bottom element $\bot$ which must be preserved by morphisms (and a ring always has a multiplicative identity $1$ which must be preserved by morphisms). For some other people, a join semilattice need not have a bottom element, but a *bounded* join semilattice does have one (and a ring need not have a multiplicative identity, but a *unital* ring does have one). Conventions like this can have an effect on the construction of coproducts, and other categorical notions.

Comment: Then for the convention,  I do not suppose the existence of a bottom element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The category of join-semilattices is a [variety of algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)), i.e. the category of models of an equational theory, in the sense of universal algebra.

In such a category, we compute the coproduct of two algebras $A$ and $B$ by taking the free algebra generated by $A$ and $B$ - roughly speaking, its domain is the set of all terms formed from the elements of $A$ and $B$, modulo the equivalence relation generated by the equational axioms and the actual term evaluations in $A$ and $B$.

Let's start with the case of (unbounded) join semilattices. These have just one operation $\vee$, and equational axioms:

- $x \vee x = x$ (idempotence)
- $x \vee y = y \vee x$ (commutativity)
- $(x\vee y) \vee z = x \vee (y \vee z)$ (associativity)

Let $A$ and $B$ be join semilattices. Then a term formed from the elements of $A$ and $B$ is an element of $A$, an element of $B$, or a join of finitely many elements from $A$ and $B$. By associativity and commutativity, a term of the third type can be rewritten as the join of (1) finitely many elements of $A$ and (2) finitely many elements of $B$. But (1) and (2) can be evaluated in $A$ and $B$, respectively, so a general term is equivalent to one of the form $a\vee b$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. So the coproduct is $$ A\sqcup B \sqcup \{a\vee b\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$$
(here $\sqcup$ denotes disjoint union) with the obvious join operation: If $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, their join is $a\vee b$. If $a,a'\in A$ and $b\in B$, then $(a\vee b) \vee a' = (a\vee a')\vee b$. If $a\in A$ and $b,b'\in B$, then $(a\vee b) \vee b' = a\vee(b\vee b')$. And if $a,a'\in A$ and $b,b'\in B$, then $(a\vee b)\vee (a' \vee b') = (a\vee a')\vee (b\vee b')$.

---

Things get a bit simpler if we consider bounded join semilattices. These have an additional constant $\bot$ and an additional equational axiom:

- $\bot \vee x = x$ (identity)

The above discussion applies, but additionally, for any $a\in A$, $a$ is equivalent to the term $a\vee \bot_B$, and for any $b\in B$, $b$ is equivalent to the term $\bot_A \vee b$. So the coproduct is
$$ \{a\vee b\mid a\in A,b\in B\}$$
with bottom element $\bot_A\vee \bot_B$ and the obvious component-wise join. Note that this is isomorphic to the product of $A$ and $B$! The category of bounded join semilattices  has biproducts (finite products and coproducts coincide), just like the categories of abelian groups or vector spaces.

---

But in the question, you asked about join semilattices with top elements. These have an additional constant $\top$ and an additional equational axiom:

- $\top \vee x = \top$

Now the above discussion applies, but we have $\top_A = \top_B = \top_A\vee b = a\vee \top_B$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Let's write $A^*$ for $A\setminus \{\top_A\}$ and similarly for $B^*$. Then the coproduct is

$$ A^*\sqcup B^* \sqcup \{a\vee b\mid a\in A^*,b\in B^*\}\sqcup \{\top\}$$

with top element $\top$ and the obvious join operation.

Comment: Sorry, because of my bad English I confused "join" with "meet" and my question was about join-semilattices with top element ... but your answer gives me ideas.

Comment: @Sov you mean "meet semilattices with top element", right? This case is dual to the case of join semilattices with bottom element (the second case handled in my answer). So the description of the coproduct is the same: just replace $\vee$ with $\wedge$ everywhere.

Comment: Yes that was I thought. Thanks a lot.

Comment: In the case of meet-semilattices with a top element, suppose you add another operation, for example the "implication" as in Heyting semilattices (also called implicative semilattices), will the coproduct still coincide with products ?

Comment: @Sov No. Here's one way to see this: there is a unique (up to isomorphism) Heyting semilattice (HSL) with two elements $\{\top,a\}$, which is the free HSL on a single generator $a$. If we let $A = \{\top,a\}$ and $B = \{\top,b\}$ be two isomorphic copies of this HSL, then the coproduct of $A$ and $B$ is the free HSL on two generators, which has $18$ elements, as shown [here](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~pjf/Heyting.pdf). But the product of $A$ and $B$ has only $4$ elements.